# Start multiple classes on App-start

Tags: android

I have an Activity for Login with buttons, etc. In the background, I want to use a fullscreen-ViewPager with some images, which provides the users some informations about the features etc.

If my manifest.xml looks like this, I only see my buttons, logo etc. and no background images:

```
<activity
       android:name="com.lo.android.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I change it to the following class, I see the background-images, but no Login buttons etc. 
How can I run multiple classes, both LoginActivity and PageIndicatorActivity on start of the App?

```
<activity
       android:name="com.lo.android.viewpager.PageIndicatorActivity">
```

LoginActivity:

```
package com.lo.android.activity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.lo.android.R;
import com.lo.android.main.Main;
import com.lo.android.service.UserTokenService;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private Button loginButton;
    private Button registerButton;
    private EditText emailInput;
    private EditText passwordInput;
    private UserTokenService userTokenService;
    private Runnable userTokenServiceCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // TODO Workaround, use Async solution
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        // End of workaround

        emailInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
        loginButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new LoginButtonClickListener());
        registerButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new RegisterButtonClickListener());

        emailInput.setText("marco.mueller@haufe-lexware.com");

        userTokenServiceCallback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JSONObject json = userTokenService.getResponse();
                try {
                    UserTokenService.userToken = json.getString("SaUser");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login erfolgreich!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    goToMain();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fehler: " + json.toString() + "\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void goToMain() {
        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Main.class);startActivity(in);
    }

    private class LoginButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = emailInput.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordInput.getText().toString();
            userTokenService = new UserTokenService(getApplicationContext(), userTokenServiceCallback);
            userTokenService.call(email, password);
        }
    }


    private class RegisterButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("https://www.lo.de/lp/registration/?cid=232"));

                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }
    }
}
```

PageIndicatorActivity:

```
package com.lo.android.viewpager;

import com.lo.android.R;
import com.lo.android.activity.LoginActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class PageIndicatorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    }
    public void login(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(PageIndicatorActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.antartica1, R.drawable.antartica2,
            R.drawable.antartica3, R.drawable.antartica4,
            R.drawable.antartica5, R.drawable.antartica6,
            R.drawable.antartica7, R.drawable.antartica8 };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just start your second Activity from your first Activity using `startActivity(Intent)`.

Comment: I have tried to do this (see PageIndicatorActivity) I see the background-Images but the LoginActivity does not start.

Comment: Are you sure your `login` method is called?

Comment: I think so...        'code' public void login(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(PageIndicatorActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }'code'